Problem with react slick: Element type is invalid
I have my component in React and I am trying to make a slider with react slick, precisely with the example code of your page but when I rederizar this component gives me the error:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
 import React from "react";
  import Slider from "react-slick";

  export default function ProductosMasVendidos() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 3, 
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    };

    return (
      <div className="slider-container">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div>
          <h3>1</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>2</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>3</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>4</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>5</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>6</h3>
        </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  
 
  
    );
  }

The idea is to show the same example slider that exists in the react slick page, when I remove the Slider component, the ProductsMostSold component will redraw correctly with everything inside.

Based on the error statement, it looks like the Slider type is an object. This seems to be a common issue among people using that library.
check this issue: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/2206

This seems to be a popular problem with the react-slick library, and I'm not sure exactly what causes the error, but itt can be fixed by adjusting your code as below:
 import React from "react";
 import Slider from "react-slick";

 export default function ProductosMasVendidos() {
  const settings = {
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   speed: 500,
   slidesToShow: 3, 
   slidesToScroll: 1,
  };

 const SliderComponent = typeof window === 'undefined' ? Slider.default : Slider;

return (
  <div className="slider-container">
   <SliderComponent {...settings}>
    ...
   </SliderComponent>
  </div>
 );
}

